# Inserting rows into DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I am currently developing a desktop application.

I have a DataTable filled up.  How do I insert those data to the DataGridView?

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude, but the question seems very naive!

Comment: Well it's either struggle for hours, or swallow my pride and ask someone else without wasting anymore time.  Which do you think is more naive?

Comment: you did good, dont reinvent the wheel.

Comment: not using google to find your answer. First. And the 2nd fault was the question itself was ambiguous *to me*. I thought perhaps you wanted an answer as to how to append data to a previously populated grid...I was confused. Again, not to sound rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
//the DataGridView
DataGridView myDataGriView = new DataGridView();

//Declare BindingSource to sync DataGridView and data table
BindingSource myBindingSource = new BindingSource();

//set the DataSource property of your BindingSource 
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;

//set the DataSource property of your DataGridView 
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

Hope it helped,

If you want more information of populating your dataTable with data from a database you can check this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database).

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable;`

If it is by any chance an ASP .NET Appication, don't forget to add

```
DataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: No, it's a desktop application.